# Regex to capture string outside of parentheses and remove comma

Tags: regex

I have a string like below

`A (1), B (2), C (1), D (3)`

that I would like to take only A B C D and remove all parentheses, comma and whitespace. I have come up with `(.*?)\s?\(.*?\),*` but it still has a whitespace for the second element (B).

Expected output is a list

```
A
B
C
D
```

I use this one https://regex101.com/ to verify

Comment: what's your expected output?

Comment: @AvinashRaj updated. Please help review.

Comment: don't know what's wrong with the below answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```js
console.log('A (1), B (2), C (1), D (3)'.replace(/[^A-Z]/g, ''));
```

You can try it on [regexr](https://regexr.com/4rv5l)

---

Update:

```js
console.log('A (1), B (2), C (1), D (3)'.replace(/[^A-Z]/g, '').replace(/([A-Z])/g, '$1\n'));
```

---

Based on @AvinashRaj's comment

```js
console.log('A (1), B (2), C (1), D (3)'.replace(/[^A-Z]+/g, '\n'));
```

Comment: Thank you very much for prompt response. I used your regex here but it didn't work https://regexr.com/. Could you please help?

Comment: @EagleDev It's working fine on [regexr](https://regexr.com/4rv5l). You can try again.

Comment: Could you click LIst to see. It doesn't work as expected. If you try the one in my question it looks good but the second element has whitespace (tab)

Comment: @EagleDev, at regex.com, you forgot the '^' sign, which negates the character range.

Comment: Use `[^A-Z]+` and replace wit \n then finally do a strip

Comment: Is there a pure regex without replace()?

Comment: @EagleDev Regex pattern is just used to match the expected string. If you want a new string based on the pattern, you must *do something* else, such as: replacing or matching then joining...

Comment: Got it. Thank you @Tân